# cannot build JavaFX 2.1.0 sample application - DataApp - failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:application

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, javafx, javafx-2

I am trying to build the DataApp sample application from the JavaFX 2.1.0 sample application pack downloadable from the official JafaFX downloads page:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html

I am using Netbeans 7.1.2, JDK6 and JavaFX 2.1.0 for JDK6.

In NetBeans, when I right-click on the DataApp server and select Run from the context menu, I get the following output:

```
check-mysql-drivers-installed:
init:
deps-module-jar:
DataAppClient.init:
Deleting: D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build\built-jar.properties
DataAppClient.deps-jar:
Updating property file: D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build\built-jar.properties
DataAppLibrary.init:
DataAppLibrary.deps-jar:
Updating property file: D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build\built-jar.properties
DataAppLibrary.compile:
Copy libraries to D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppLibrary\dist\lib.
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppLibrary\dist\DataAppLibrary.jar"
DataAppLibrary.jar:
Duplicated project name in import. Project jfx-impl defined first in D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml and again in D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppPreloader\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml
DataAppPreloader.init:
DataAppPreloader.deps-jar:
Updating property file: D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build\built-jar.properties
DataAppPreloader.compile:
Copying 1 file to D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppPreloader\build
Copy libraries to D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppPreloader\dist\lib.
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
C:\jdk1.6.0_30/bin/java -jar "D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppPreloader\dist\DataAppPreloader.jar"
Deleting directory D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppPreloader\dist\lib
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.1
DataAppPreloader.jfx-deployment:
DataAppPreloader.jar:
DataAppClient.compile:
Copying 27 files to D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\dist\lib
Moving 1 file to D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\dist
Expanding: D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\dist\lib\DataAppLibrary.jar into D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build\classes
Expanding: D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\dist\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.jar into D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build\classes
Expanding: D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\dist\lib\jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar into D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build\classes
Expanding: D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\dist\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.1.jar into D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build\classes
Expanding: D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\dist\lib\jackson-xc-1.7.1.jar into D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build\classes
Expanding: D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\dist\lib\jersey-client-1.8.jar into D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build\classes
Expanding: D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\dist\lib\jersey-core-1.8.jar into D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build\classes
Expanding: D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\dist\lib\jersey-json-1.8.jar into D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build\classes
Deleting directory D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\dist\lib
D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppServer\nbproject\build-impl.xml:559: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build.xml:48: Problem: failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:application
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Does anybody have any idea about this error?

Could it be somehow related to Ant ?

What do the following lines mean?

```
The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Soft\javafx-samples-2.1.0\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build.xml:48: Problem: failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:application
Cause: The name is undefined.
```

Thank you!

Update:
Aparently the problem is solved by manually modifying the Ant build.xml file located in the DataAppClient project root.
I added a taskdef tag at the beginning of the -post-jar target definition and the error was gone:

```
...

<target name="-post-jar" depends="-init-javafx, -jfx-copylibs">

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
             uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
             classpath="d:\Soft\javafx_sdk_2.1\lib\ant-javafx.jar" />

    <!-- Move preloader out of libs -->
    <move file="${dist.dir}/lib/DataAppPreloader.jar" todir="${dist.dir}"/>

...
```

Can this be an error in the official release of this sample application, or something is wrong with my setup ?

Comment: DataApp requires infrastructure to be setup. There is README in the project, take a look.

Comment: I have read the documentation and performed the steps shown in the readme uptil this point.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed an actual question. DataAppClient should be based on "Default JavaFX Platform" in NetBeans which includes, for instance, ant tasks definition. If you didn't setup that platform or didn't use it for DataAppClient project you may opt to add taskdef manually. Which worked for you.

Comment: That would explain it, I didn't have that configuration, probably because I opted out the JavaFX package that came with NetBeans [during the NetBeans installation wizard] and preferred to manually download and configure JavaFX.

Comment: Can you, please, answer your own question with info you've find out and accept such answer (it's common practice, so other user would be able to see this question as answered)

Comment: Sorry for the long time it took for me to answer this question, I an still learning how to properly use this website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparently the problem is solved by manually modifying the Ant build.xml file located in the DataAppClient project root.
I added a taskdef tag at the beginning of the -post-jar target definition and the error was gone:

```
...

<target name="-post-jar" depends="-init-javafx, -jfx-copylibs">

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
             uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
             classpath="d:\Soft\javafx_sdk_2.1\lib\ant-javafx.jar" />

    <!-- Move preloader out of libs -->
    <move file="${dist.dir}/lib/DataAppPreloader.jar" todir="${dist.dir}"/>

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who has a similar error. Try the following solution (it worked for me), I found it here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/efxclipse/H-ZOVXtaK6g/5yufMqQsZBQJ

The Solution

I managed to get it to work by going to Run->External Tools_>External Tools Configurations and selecting JRE Tab.  I had to change the Execution environment from 1.7 to CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0 (jdk1.7.0_25) (and CDC-1.1 also works).

The Error-

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Ross\workspace\MyJavaFXApp\build\build.xml:87: Problem: failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:resources

Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet
```