# Cannot run DataApp sample application in Netbeans 7.1.2

Tags: xml, netbeans

This is the challenge am facing when running the sample DataApp application from the samples javafx2.1 package: I'm running Netbeans 7.1.2, javafx 2.1.,glassfish 3.1.2, Java EE6, and i have 6gig ram.

When i right-click on the DataAppServer project or i do same with the DataAppClient project and hit Run, i get this error message:

```
C:\Users\Staples\Desktop\ITOWER STUDIO\javafx-samples-2.1.1\src\DataApp\DataAppServer\nbproject\build-impl.xml:533: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Staples\Desktop\ITOWER STUDIO\javafx-samples-2.1.1\src\DataApp\DataAppClient\build.xml:48: Problem: failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:application
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet
BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)**
```

I tried adding a taskdef tag as explained in a similar question but it gives the same error. There was no error when i opened the projects and connected to the MySQL database. Here is the taskdef tag i added:

```
<taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
    uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
    classpath="C:\Program Files(x86)\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 SDK\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
```

Line 48 shows this string:

```
preloaderClass="dataapppreloader.DataAppPreloader"/>
```

and Line 533 shows :

```
<ant antfile="${project.DataAppClient}/build.xml" inheritall="false"target="jar">
```

Am really stuck here. need help. Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (JavaFX 2.2b13, JavaFX Samples 2.2b11, jdk7u6ea, NetBeans 7.1.2).  When I open the DataAppClient project in NetBeans from the samples directory, then right click and say run, the project just builds and runs - no errors or need to add any taskdef tag.  (The javafx ant tasks are defined in the nbproject/jfx-impl.xml file which is already included in the project build).

Answer (score 0):

This helps:
[cannot build JavaFX 2.1.0 sample application - DataApp - failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753949/cannot-build-javafx-2-1-0-sample-application-dataapp-failed-to-create-task-o)

.. which tells you to add

```
          <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
             uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
             classpath="C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 SDK\lib\ant-javafx.jar" />
```

under the line

```
 <target name="-post-jar" depends="-init-javafx, -jfx-copylibs">
```

in the build.xml file in the DataAppclient folder